# Lanthanide bond lengths and dissociation

Tags: inorganic-chemistry

Due to lanthanide contraction, covalent character increases and ionic character decreases in lanthanides. Since a covalent bond is weaker than an ionic bond, $\ce{Lu(OH)3}$ should dissociate more easily than $\ce{La(OH)3}$. But that is not the case. Why?